# How can I sort objects by date if date type is "16.11 11:20"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, datetime

I'm trying to sort objects in an array by date.
There is this kind of array with objects and the date is written in this format "14.9 15:11". date is string.
How do I sort objects so that the first one is the one with the closest date to the current one?

```
[
 {
  date: "16.11 11:20",
  name: "Name Surname"
 },
 {
  date: "15.11 19:59",
  name: "Name Surname"
 },
 {
  date: "17.11 17:24",
  name: "Name Surname"
 },
 {
  date: "14.9 15:11",
  name: "Name Surname"
 }
]
```

Comment: Do you know what the format is? Take for example the first date `16.11 11:20` I would assume that `16.11` signifies the 16th day of the 11th month and `11:20` is the time in hours and minutes. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: What will happen once a new year starts? How do you expect to know that `31.12`, not `1.3`, is the closest date to `1.1`?

Comment: Yes you understand correct. I already sort it by using localeCompare. Thank you for interesting my question)

Comment: When you say closest, do you mean closest before, closest after, or closest in either direction?

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to use `moment.js` in cases where I work with dates, because it makes everything so much simpler.

However if you're looking for a vanilla function you can create your own custom sort function to use as a callback for sort.

```
const yourArray = [...];
yourArray.sort((next, prev) => {
  if (condition1)
    return 1;
  if (condition2)
    return -1;
  return 0;
})
```

Then you can compare the strings in place of `condition1` and `condition2` based on a regexp of your chosing, depending on your date format.  But again, this would all be way easier for you if you use moment as you can then use their inbuilt `ìsBefore()` and `ìsAfter()` compare functions instead of having to write regexps.